# Beneficiary question on Small Estate Affidavit

Tags: new-york-state, wills

I am going through the Small Estate Affidavit DIY Forms for a spouse.
Location is the state of New York, US.

One of the questions is "Are there beneficiaries other than you in the decedent's will"?  I have to answer Yes or No.

My spouse's will says "All of my estate...I give...unto my spouse."

In the next section, it says "In the event my spouse predeceases me...I give...my entire estate...unto my children..." Then, "In the event any of my children predecease me...I direct that my estate be divided...as follows".  Then eight contingent beneficiaries are listed.

How should I answer the beneficiaries question in the Small Estate Affidavit form?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is apparent from information in the question:

> "Are there beneficiaries other than you in the decedent's will?"

> "...eight contingent beneficiaries are listed."

Presuming the eight contingent beneficiaries are *not* you, the answer would be "yes".

Presumably there is an opportunity within the form to make it clear that they are contingent.